# Creating new jQuery object.create(newobj) 2x overwrites initial object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype

I'm trying to add new `<li>` elements to an existing mobile menu, and this script works, except that the second Object.create(x) overwrites the already-appended first object. I'm very confused why that is. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.

The script is getting the text and url from two different `<a>` tags, i.e., `#c_top-nav-link-01` and `#c_top-nav-link-02`and trying to make new `<li>` tags with that information.

The first `if` statement generates a new `<li>` object that then appends to the `<ul>` I'm targeting, but when the second `if` statement runs, rather than appending a second `li` element with new properties, it simply replaces the first, already-appended `<li>` element.

Thoughts? Anything obvious I'm missing?

```
    ;(function ( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready( function () {
        $( '.lia-slide-out-nav-menu' ).click( function ( e ) {
            console.log( 'clicked' );
            let mobileNav = $( "ul" ).first();


            const newLI = {
                newNavItem : $( '<li class="some-icon"></li>' ),
                newAnchor  : $( '<a class="some-link" href="#" title="#"></a>' ),
                newIconItem: $( '<span class="circle-icon-left" role="img" aria-label="Category"></span>' ),
                newTextItem: $( '<span class="item-text"></span>' ),
                newNavRight: $( '<span class="chevron-icon-right" role="img" aria-label="click to open this category"></span>' )
            }

            if ( $( "#c_top-nav-link-01" ) ) {

                let firstLI = Object.create( newLI );
                let link01 = $( "#c_top-nav-link-01" );
                link01.text = link01.text();
                link01.url = link01.prop( "href" );
                console.log( 'link01.text', link01.text );
                firstLI.newAnchor.prop( "href", link01.url );
                firstLI.newTextItem.text( link01.text );
                firstLI.newAnchor.append( [firstLI.newIconItem, firstLI.newTextItem, firstLI.newNavRight] );

                firstLI.newNavItem.append( firstLI.newAnchor );
                mobileNav.append( firstLI.newNavItem );
            }

            if ( $( "#c_top-nav-link-02" ) ) {

                let secondLI = Object.create( newLI );
                let link02 = $( "#c_top-nav-link-02" );
                link02.text = link02.text();
                link02.url = link02.prop( "href" );
                console.log( 'link02.text', link02.text );
                secondLI.newAnchor.prop( "href", link02.url );
                secondLI.newTextItem.text( link02.text );
                secondLI.newAnchor.append( [secondLI.newIconItem, secondLI.newTextItem, secondLI.newNavRight] );
                secondLI.newNavItem.append( secondLI.newAnchor );
                mobileNav.append( secondLI.newNavItem );
            }

        } );

    } );
})(jQuery );
```

The target is a dynamically generated unordered list that I do not have the ability to tap into and add these list items to the dynamic generation, i.e.,

```
<ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
    <li>item three</li>
</ul>
```

I just want to add the new `<li>` items to the list after "item three"

Comment: Why are you using `Object.create` at all, instead of jQuery's [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)?

Comment: `Object.create` is unlikely to work with DOM elements...

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) doesn't clone an object, it creates a new object with the supplied object set as the prototype. `newLI.newNavItem === firstLI.newNavItem` is `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function newLi(props, target) {
    var item = $("<li>", {
      class: props.class
    });
    if (target != undefined) {
      item.appendTo(target);
    }
    $("<a>", props.link).appendTo(item);
    $("<span>", props.icon).appendTo($("a", item));
    $("<span>", props.text).html(props.text.content).appendTo($("a", item));
    return item;
  }

  $('.lia-slide-out-nav-menu').click(function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    var mobileNav = $("ul").first();

    if ($("#c_top-nav-link-01").length) {
      newLi({
        class: "some-icon",
        link: {
          class: "some-link",
          href: $("#c_top-nav-link-01").attr("href"),
          title: "#"
        },
        icon: {
          class: "circle-icon-left",
          role: "img",
          "aria-label": "Category"
        },
        text: {
          class: "item-text",
          content: $("#c_top-nav-link-01").text()
        }
      }, mobileNav);
    }

    if ($("#c_top-nav-link-02").length) {
      newLi({
        class: "some-icon",
        link: {
          class: "some-link",
          href: $("#c_top-nav-link-02").attr("href"),
          title: "#"
        },
        icon: {
          class: "circle-icon-left",
          role: "img",
          "aria-label": "Category"
        },
        text: {
          class: "item-text",
          content: $("#c_top-nav-link-02").text()
        }
      }, mobileNav);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lia-slide-out-nav-menu">...</div>
<div class="slide-out-menu-links">
  <ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
    <li>item three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a id="c_top-nav-link-01" href="page1.htm">Link 1</a>
<a id="c_top-nav-link-02" href="page2.htm">Link 2</a>
```

You can also use `.clone()` to clone the `a` element like so:

```
var newLink = $("#c_top-nav-link-01").clone();
```

You just have to remember to adjust the ID attribute before appending it.

This example performs a similar function, yet it builds out more structure. You could do this with a `<template>` too if you wanted. it would give you the HTML Structure and then you could copy it as needed and populate it.

Your `if` statements would always be `true` the way you were using them. If you want to check if an element with that selector exists, you need to call the `length` attribute. This will return `0` if no elements exist or `1` or higher. `0` will equate to `false` and `1` or more will equate to `true`

Comment: @MaxRocket have worked in Tech Support for years and get to flex those skills here.